# Downgrade Evoq content to DNN platform

Tags: content-management-system, dotnetnuke

Can anyone from DNN community know how to downgrade Evoq Content to Basic DNN platform.
Please mentiond the step by step process to do that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no documented "downgrade" path, and in fact it is depending on things like which extensions (modules etc.) you use that are only available in Evoq, which version of Evoq you use and which version of the platform you want to have at the end. For the extensions you need some replacement.

There are some people in the Community who have already done such jobs successfully. I would recommend to post this question in the [DNN Community Forums](https://dnncommunity.org/forums), this is the place to find experts.

Comment: Thanks Michael.

Comment: @ratikantrautra, even though it wasn't your final solution, Michael's answer (above) is about as good as it gets and IMHO you should "check it" - mark it as the accepted answer.